# How to replace string into string in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, replace

I want to replace some text in a string with another string.

For example : A string equals to "Red small car". 
I want to replace "small" with "big" so the string becomes
"Red big car". I have to do this in swift. Thanks.

Comment: He's a newbie, please don't dislike him. It will make him disappointed about StackOverflow.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
let string = "Big red car"
let replaced = (string as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Big", withString: "Small")
```

**Edit**
**In Swift 5**

```
import Foundation

let string = "Big red car"
let replaced = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "Big", with: "Small")
```

Comment: This gives me an error in REPL: `error: cannot invoke 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' with an argument list of type '(StringLiteralConvertible, withString: StringLiteralConvertible)'`, w.o. the cast, it works.

Comment: @SebastianDressler: Which Xcode version are you using? That code compiles and works fine (as well as yours) in Xcode 6.1.1. Of course, using NSString in the REPL requires that you `import Foundation`. – Anyway, this question has already been asked and answered (probably more than once).

Comment: @MartinR it is 6.1.1 and I imported `Foundation`. Very strange...

Comment: @SebastianDressler: Indeed.

Comment: For Swift 3, you will want to use `let replaced = string.replacingOccurrences(of:"Big" with "Small")`

Comment: @AlexShaffer   the comma should be added before "with", also colon be added after "with":
`let replaced = string.replacingOccurrences(of:"Big", with:"Small")`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, e.g.

```
let s1 : String = "Red small car"
let s2 = s1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("small", withString: "big")
```

Comment: replacingOccurrences(of:,with:) in swift 4